# Database of font information

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I'm looking for a database of font information, specifically limited to those found on Linotype. For example, given the typeface CRONOS, I'd like to be able to know if it is:

(sans/slab) serif?
monospaced?
display?
script?

I can certainly look at a font by hand and decide this for myself, but I'd like a a database or tool out there that determines this. I've looked at the Linux program `otfinfo` but it does not give any of this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer may seem a little too obvious, but if you go to fonts.com (which has ALL the same fonts as linotype.com but features more extensive descriptions) and find the [Cronos page](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/cronos), you will see a short article on the top of the page and Category as well as the tags in the right column.

Both article and category say it's a humanist sans serif typeface.

Actually, searching the font shops for the classification (like [fonts.com](http://fonts.com), [myfonts.com](http://myfonts.com), [fontshop.com](http://fontshop.com) etc.) is the best way to find out how the particular typeface is classified because there are (a) no strict criteria for many classification groups, and (b) a lot of fonts "in the middle" between two or even more categories.

The classification displayed at different font marketplaces is usually either suggested by the author of the font or sometimes decided by the experienced staff.

Comment: This will work - `fonts.com` has a "category" and tag section. I can use that to pull some information. Thanks!